# Editing IIS with shared config through the Microsoft.Web.Administration namespace

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019

We are having a problem, and it's probably something completely stupid. We have the following setup:

WebCluster1 (A cluster of IIS web servers running a administration site)
WebCluster2 (A Cluster of IIS web servers running another site)
NAS (A Nas containing web configs for the servers)

A user has the option to create users on the sites hosted on WebCluster1, and these users are then written into the webconfig on WebCluster2. However we have had a problem with this for some time now. Since the workflow goes like this:

User creates a user on WebCluster1 --> WebCluster1 contacts a server in WebCluster2 by using the [Microsoft.Web.Administration namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration?view=iis-dotnet) and tries to add the user to the webconfig --> WebCluster2 tries to write the change to the config on the NAS and fails.

The setup works if we remove the NAS and it works if we try to edit the webconfig directly on the servers in WebCluster2. This leads to us believing it's a double hop issue, but is there any way to solve this? Have we just made the dumbest decision? Is there a better way to do this?